# json renderer for HTTPException in pyramid

Tags: python, json, pyramid

I have the following code snippet:

```
try:
    DBSession.query(Task).filter_by(id=task_id).one()
except NoResultFound:
    raise HTTPNotFound
```

I would like to return this as `application/json` response. It works fine for the try clause, however, if exception is raised - it is returned as `text/html`. I know I can manually construct response like so:

```
response = HTTPNotFound()
response.content_type = 'application/json'
response.text = {'message': 'not found'}
return response
```

However, it is very inconvenient to do this way every time. Another possible solution is to use `@view_config` decorator:

```
@view_config(context=HTTPNotFound, renderer='json')
def not_found(request):
    return {'message': 'not found'}
```

and then raising that exception uses this view. However, I can't make it application wide. If I move this view function into `__init__.py`, it stops being called. So my question is, how to return `json` response rather than `html` from any exception that I raise in my app?

Comment: `@view_config` is used with `config.scan()`, you could replace this with a `config.add_view(...)` and it would do the same thing. Now you can place it in your `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/renderers.html#adding-a-default-renderer):

> To associate a default renderer with all view configurations (even
> ones which do not possess a renderer attribute), pass None as the name
> attribute to the renderer tag:
>
> `config.add_renderer(None, 'mypackage.json_renderer_factory')`

In your case:

```
config.add_renderer(None, 'pyramid.renderers.json_renderer_factory')
```

Comment: If I understand that correctly, adding this to the main `config.add_renderer(None, 'pyramid.renderers.JSON')` should do the trick? However, doesn't seem to be working, I still get html.

Comment: `config.add_renderer(None, 'pyramid.renderers.json_renderer_factory')`

Comment: Looked at the code, json_renderer_factory is left for backwards compatibility and points to JSON. Nevertheless, I tried both, and both times got exactly the same html output.

Answer (score 0):

add_renderer expects factory implementation

```
json_renderer_factory = JSON()
```

Second solution (overwrite [exception view](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html#exception-views)) exactly should work. Are you enable declarative configuration in your project? Try to use imperative style config.add_view(...). Also, try to check logs, mb another view is called with context= HTTPNotFound

Answer (score -1):

Add in ____init__.py

```
def request_factory(environ):
    environ['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/json'
    request = Request(environ)
    request.response = Response()
    request.add_response_callback(finish_callback)
    return request

def finish_callback(peticion, respuesta):
    respuesta.headerlist.extend(
        (
            ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
            ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'WWW-Authorization'),
            ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'),
        )
    )
    return respuesta
```

Later, add the request_factory in **main()**:

```
config.set_request_factory(request_factory)
```

Works for me. It is not the best option, but it works for me

Source:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/httpexceptions.html
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html